# Do not know how to test angular.bootstrap wrapper

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

I'm writing unit test for our code and I have some functionality that uses angular.bootstrap and I have no idea how to test it using karma as by then is not part of any module or anything

```
(function () {
'use strict';

function fetchData() {

    var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);

    var $http = initInjector.get('$http');

    return $http.get('./app/config/app.config.json').then(function (response) {
        angular.module('myModule').value('globalConfig', response.data);
        return $http.get('./app/config/routes.config.json').then(function (response) {
            angular.module('myModule').value('routesConfig', response.data);
        }, function (errorResponse) {
            // Handle error case
            console.log('Error on loading routes:', errorResponse);
        });
    }, function (errorResponse) {
        // Handle error case
        console.log('Error on bootstrapping:', errorResponse);
    });
}

function bootstrapApplication() {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myModule']);
    });
}

fetchData().then(bootstrapApplication);
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refactor this block to belong to a regular angular service so that it is testable. For example (and I've assumed your calls can run in parallel):

```
angular.module('myBootstrapModule', [])

  .factory('bootstrap', function($q, $http) {
    return function(moduleName) {
      return $q.all([
        $http.get('./app/config/app.config.json'),
        $http.get('./app/config/routes.config.json')
      ])
        .then(function(results) {
           angular.module(moduleName)
             .value('globalConfig', results[0].data)
             .value('routesConfig', results[1].data);
        })
        .catch(function(res) {
          // handle error
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Bootstrapping can then be achieved by manually creating an injector that includes this module, while testing can take place as normal by loading the `myBootstrapModule`:

```
var injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'myBootstrapModule']);
var bootstrap = injector.get('bootstrap');

bootstrap('myModule').then(function() {
  // bootstrap angular
});
```